# I have a problem with Jupyter notebook. I'm getting errors in my computer, but in another the error doesn't happen

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I'm using windows 11 in my computer and in the computer of work.
In my personal computer i try to run a code and a error appears, but I try the same code, same files in the computer of work and the code run normally.

I want to create a column from another, transforming the values in the first column into float. Thats the code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
jeopardy = pd.read_csv('jeopardy.csv')
jeopardy.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)

print(jeopardy.head())

jeopardy["Value_float"] = jeopardy['Value'].apply(lambda x: float(x[1:].replace(',',"")))
```

The error is:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

But this just happen in my computer. Is there an update or something I can change on my computer?
​

Comment: Is the `jeopardy.csv` file identical on both computers?

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `jeopardy['Value']`? Is it already a float?

Comment: The file is identical

Comment: The `dtype` isnt float yet, Is object